# How to totally disable HDMI audio through Nvidia / Pulseaudio?

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, usb, pulseaudio, hdmi

Original thread title: HDMI input switching causing popping / crackling with USB Audio - Pulseaudio problem?

Original post:

I seem to be having issues with HDMI effectively sending noise back to my PC when disconnecting or changing inputs on my HDMI switch.

I don't use HDMI for audio and have disabled any HDMI audio in pulseaudio.

I have limited space on my desk and my monitor only has 1 HDMI port so I just want to use that and have ben using a 5 way HDMI switch for years. However, recently, whenever i change from one input back to my PC, a load of crackling and popping randomly on the right or left channel seems to occur during playback of any audio for quite some time. If I don't change inputs again on the HDMI switch for 10 minutes or so, this noise can eventually go.

For my audio, I use a USB DAC and as it is digital, I don't see why I should be getting this interference. Even when switching HDMI inputs, i get a brief half second pause of my computor audio, and that seems to be when it gets messed up. The strange thing is that if I use the headphone/speaker output from the motherboard or front of my PC, the HDMI switch does not introduce this crackling and popping, so why would the digital output such as USB do this? That in my opinion should be far cleaner!

Another way I tested this to see if it wasn't my HDMI switch at fault was to use an HDMI right from my PC to my monitor. Unplugging it from my monitor doesn't do anything to the audio, but plugging it back in instantly introduces all this noise in the same way as switching back to my pc input on my HDMI switch. If I use DVI from my graphics card to my monitor and repeat this process, the noise is never a problem.
I then thought I could maybe get a DVI to HDMI cable to prevent audio going to the HDMI switch or bouncing back to my PC which I expected would sort the issue out, only to read that these adaptors/cables if used in the orientation i planned literally act just like an HDMI cable and also carry audio.

I am wondering is pulse audio is the problem and when i switch inputs and goes back, it briefly sees the HDMI as an audio option and then switches back to USB, but has been messed up by the switch. What I'm hoping is that it is this and that there is a way to entirely disable audio from the graphics card so changing inputs on my monitor or HDMI switch will never cut out out interfere with my USB DAC. I have 3 USB DACS and have tested all of them so I know these are not at fault either.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Edit - Now more related to the edited name:

I now know this problem isn't related to the type of cable used, and is more related to if it has the ability to carry audio.

I've tried 3 HDMI cables and now 1 DVI to HDMI cable. My graphics card still seems to allow audio through the DVI connector and cable to the HDMI switch at the other end.

More steps I have tried is connecting an HDMI cable up directly to my monitor while playing audio through my USB DAC. If I disconnect the HDMI cable and plug it back in (same as changing input on my HDMI switch) that also introduces this noise to my USB DAC when playing audio for several minutes after. If I use a DVI - DVI cable directly to my monitor and change inputs, I don't have any problem other than having to plug another cable into my monitor that i don't want to.

I am now almost 100% certain that if there was somehow a way to disable any possibility of audio going down the HDMI cable, this issue would be gone. I never want to use HDMI audio with my PC and can't imagine i ever will, so totally disabling it should help i hope. But in pulseaudio, it is off. Maybe it briefly comes back on, then off and that messes it up when changing inputs?

Comment: Most likely it is a lower quality HDMI cable It does not seem to have anything to do with software. I have the same issue on some speakers I have when I unplug them and plug them back in noise for a second or two..

Comment: I did a lot of research on this when my speakers were doing this and I found answers like the humidity was to low but mostly that I needed better cables. I replaced the cables problem solved. For my TV attached to computer using HDMI I had to remove the audio cable and only use the HDMI cable for video and audio. I have 2 Ubuntu machines configured as HTPC.

Comment: Could be, one can only try.